# Search in the database with a where clause>0

Tags: php, pdo

Hi guys I wont search in the database for records, for get the number of the records,I wont do a thing like that with PDO:

```
$Data=$connection->prepare("SELECT URL FROM SITES WHERE Number>0");
$connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 
$NWords=$Data->rowCount();
echo "$NWords";
```

Comment: Where is the execute?

Comment: https://phpdelusions.net/pdo_examples/count

Comment: look into "COUNT"

Answer (score 0):

Your code isn't correct.
Try this

```
$connection->prepare("SELECT URL FROM SITES WHERE Number>0");
$connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$connection->execute(); 
echo $connection->rowCount();
```